# Gitignore Laravel vendor folder

Tags: php, mysql, git, laravel, version-control

Right now I have **/vendor** set in my gitignore file.

But how do I ignore all folders inside **/vendor** except one folder.

Eg: I want git to track **/vendor/MyFolder** but not any other folders in **/vendor**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a `.gitignore` you can use the `!` operator to "unignore" files.

The following example will ignore everything in the `vendor` directory, but anything in `vendor/MyFolder` will be "unignored"

```
vendor/
!vendor/MyFolder
```